# OSX Tomcat access via VirtualBox Windows 7

Tags: windows, macos, tomcat, virtualbox

I'm trying to access my Tomcat instance on OSX with Windows 7 via VirtualBox.

My network settings on VirtualBox:
Adapater 1: Bridged Adapter
Name: en1: Wi-Fi (Airport)

Adapter 2: Host-only Adapter
Name: vboxnet0

my ifconfig -a from OSX:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

I can ping my OSX box from Windows 7, but when I try to visit http://192.168.56.1:8080 I simply get an error that looks like I'm not connected.

Any ideas?  Am I missing something in my OSX settings?

edit:

netstat -lan |grep 8080:

```
    tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: What is the result of `netstat -lan | grep 8080`on OSX ? Does Tomcat listen on all IP addresses ?

Comment: @BGR Original post edited with netstat's results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Adapter 1: NAT
Adapter 2: Disabled